# MVC same view for both display and edit

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have the a partial view use to edit the person details in the popup dialog, but they also want to have "display" mode, which disabled all editable textbox, dropdownlistbox and links in the view, can someone tell me how easy I can achieve this (not using javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same view with conditionals to disable the editor, but that gets messy really quickly. A better approach is to have a seperate cshtml file for the editable view and specify the appropriate view name in the call to View or RenderPartial.

Comment: which means I have to create the exactly same markup with just additional css attribute like disabled="disabled" or readonly="true", that's what I am doing at the moment. The reason I ask is coz I recently received a request to make the change of this kind of view (which we had a lot in the apps). I am looking a better way to implement it.

Comment: You should use display templates for the read only views, and editor templates for the writeable views (e.g form). you shouldn't manually be adding disabled classes (unless that's the actual visual effect youre after)

Comment: Doing it that way looks awful compared to textboxes for editable stuff and just text for the bits you can't change. If that's what your client really wants it might be reasonable to use conditionals (though I would use the syntax `class='@(Model.IsEditable ? "enabled" : "disabled")'`. Even then it would probably be better to use separate templates - it isn't significant duplication, and makes it easy to improve when the client realises how bad the combined version looks.

Comment: To: RPM1984 , I had a lot of dropdown listbox, the display/edit template doesn't work quite good